# Change HAML indentation from 2 to 4 spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Is there a way to change the indentation from 2 spaces to 4 spaces for HAML on a Ruby on Rails application?

If I failed to indent properly, I get: `The line was indented 2 levels deeper than the previous line.`

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea. Why would you want to change this? Because of your IDE who puts 4 spaces instead of 2 by default? If yes, this can be customized.

Comment: I want to change it because I find 2 space indentation to difficult to read. What makes it a bad idea? Is there a technical reason why it needs to be 2?

Comment: Its just basic style guidance: https://github.com/dcompute/styleguides/tree/master/haml#basic-conventions - Have you tried different fonts/sizes to make code more readable?

Comment: @ddubs Be that as it may, assuming I was so inclined to ignore style guidance (which I am), is there a way to change the indentation? Of course as a last result I'll modify my editor to get around this limitation.

Comment: I'm just surprised there isn't `config.haml.indent_spaces = 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/#indentation

> Haml’s indentation can be made up of one or more tabs or spaces.
>   However, indentation must be consistent within a given document. Hard
>   tabs and spaces can’t be mixed, and the same number of tabs or spaces
>   must be used throughout.

Here's my test:

test.haml

```
#content
    .title
        %h1 Test
```

Results:

```
haml test.haml

<div id='content'>
<div class='title'>
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Neat, looks like the first indentation is what is uses to determine what the rest of the document should be. Solved my problem. Thanks!